# Windows 10: A file and folder ownership mess and how to fix it

Tags: windows-10, ownership

In Windows 10 Pro 64 v 1903

I had a [problem changing access permissions for a new user](https://superuser.com/questions/1499669/windows-10-error-applying-security-on-new-account-failed-to-enumerate-objects), and a comment on my question about that told me to check the ownership of the folders appearing in the error messages. When I did, I found that their owner name is not that of my account, but is a [security ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) (SID). The commenter then suggested that I change the ownership of those folders to my admin account. Because this involves a huge number of files, I didn't want to just change the whole directory tree without checking on the current status of ownership. So I used PowerShell to give me a spreadsheet of all my ownerships. I've never looked at ownerships before and I don't know what to make of the results. In particular, I wonder if I need to be concerned about (a) ownerships that are empty, (b) ownerships that are SIDs, and (c) files and folders on my data drive that are not owned by my account.

Here is a summary of the ownerships I found. Drive C is the system drive and has no user-generated data. (I don't use the desktop or Windows' default folders for documents, downloads, etc.) Drive D is my data drive, but also has some system-generated folders and files, as described in the notes below.

```
Owner                                                  Drive C      Drive D
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
(empty)                                                    365            7
BUILTIN\Administrators                                  57,512        3,320
<ComputerName>\Administrator                                 2
<ComputerName>\<AdminUserName>                          29,568        7,551
NT AUTHORITY\IUSR                                                         2
NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE                                 794
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE                               166
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM                                    152,389            4
NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller                             89,829            1
O:S-1-5-21-156xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-1003                          5
O:S-1-5-21-229xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-1000              4
O:S-1-5-21-229xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-1002             20            2
O:S-1-5-21-297xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-1017            18
O:S-1-5-21-341xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-1000                    183,706
O:S-1-5-21-397xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-4882392             2
Window Manager\DWM-1                                         4
                                                       -------      -------
                                                       330,673      194,598
```

Notes on the ownerships on C:

- **Empty**:

  - Five system-generated files in the root folder: "hyberfil.sys", "pagefile.sys", "swapfile.sys", and two encryption data files.
  - Several ".dll" and ".bin" files
  - Many empty folders
  - Hundreds of ".png" files in folders under "C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\"
- **`<ComputerName>\Administrator`**:

  - Two ".regtrans-ms" files in "C:\Windows\appcompat\Programs"
- **O:S-1-5-21-229...-1000**:

  - A folder in the recycle bin ("D:\$RECYCLE.BIN") and the only file in that folder, "desktop.ini"
  - Two ".sys" files in paths containing my computer manufacturer's name
- **O:S-1-5-21-229...-1002**:

  - A folder in the recycle bin and the only file in that folder, "desktop.ini"
  - Two ".sys" files in paths containing my computer manufacturer's name
  - Six empty folders and ".log" files in paths containing "Norton" or "Symantec"
  - One file without an extension under "C:\Windows\System32\"
  - Nine ".tmp" files in "C:\Windows\Temp\"
- **O:S-1-5-21-227...-1017**:

  - 18 ".regtrans-ms" files under "C:\Users\Default" and "C:\Windows\System32\"
- **O:S-1-5-21-397...-4882392**:

  - Two ".regtrans-ms" files under "C:\Windows\System32\"

Notes on the ownerships on D:

- **Empty**:

  - Two system-generated encryption data files
  - The only five files on D with filespecs larger than 255 (all user-generated)
- **BUILTIN\Administrators**:

  - One system-generated encryption data file
  - One system-generated, hidden folder, "D:\System Volume Information"
  - Some copies of system-generated files, such as ".dmp" and ".xml" files retrieved after a blue-screen crash and a Symantec ".sdbz" file, as well as copies of some software installation ".exe" files
  - Many files in the recycle bin ("D:\$RECYCLE.BIN")
  - Thousands of user-generated files, including txt, png, htm, php, and pdf files, and some user-generated folders
- **NT AUTHORITY\IUSR**:

  - Two user-generated files, a txt and a csv.
- **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM**:

  - The root "D:\"
  - One folder in the recycle bin
  - Two system-generated, hidden folders: "D:\Recovery" and "D:\Recovery\Logs"
- **NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller**:

  - A folder in the recycle bin
- **O:S-1-5-21-156...-1003**:

  - A folder in the recycle bin
  - Four user-generated folders
- **O:S-1-5-21-229...-1002**:

  - A folder in the recycle bin and the only file in that folder, "desktop.ini"
- **O:S-1-5-21-341...-1000**:

  - Over 180,000 folders and files, which as far as I can tell are all user-generated. These are not contiguous, but are interspersed with folders and files owned by BUILTIN\Administrators and `<ComputerName>\<AdminUserName>`.

I've never dealt with the concept of ownership before, so I don't know how unusual these results are. But it does seem that there at least might be a problem with the SID owners because I was [not able to change the access permissions for a new user](https://superuser.com/questions/1499669/windows-10-error-applying-security-on-new-account-failed-to-enumerate-objects) on folders that have those owners. So, as mentioned above, my questions are:

- Are the empty ownerships something to be concerned about and fixed?
- Should I change some or all of the SID ownerships to be owned by my account?
- Should I do a recursive change of all files and folders on the data drive (D:) to make them be owned by my account?
- Is there anything else I should be concerned about with this?
- Is there anything more you need to know in order to answer these questions?

Comment: It doesn't *necessarily* matter if a file or folder has no owner. Provided the security permissions are correct, everything will be functionally okay as far as security and access is concerned. I would have skipped the whole PowerShell bit because that just overcomplicates things here. Also, if you do ever interrupt applying permissions, which inevitably leaves a messy inconsistent-state situation, you always want to re-run it and let it finish so it can clean itself up, rather than leaving the mess to cause unexpected issues in the future. That's one corner you never want to cut!

Comment: All you needed to do was: 1) take ownership of the confidential folder on D and *wait as long as it takes to finish!* 2) Then simply remove the guest account's NTFS permissions and again... *wait as long as it takes to apply again!*

Comment: @MrEthernet - Can you answer this: Re D:, should I change ownership of everything on D: to my account, including the system generated files on it, or just change the SID owners? Re C:, since it seems that the SID owners caused the change of permissions to fail, should I change all the SID owners on C: to my account?

Comment: The system-generated files in the root of C *already* don't allow users to modify them, so they're already out of harm's way as far as this guest user is concerned. Try renaming hiberfil.sys even from your admin account and you'll see what I mean! You don't want to mess with anything deep inside Windows, you'll most likely do more damage than a careless user ever would. I would hide the Windows folder from them but if they're smart and potentially devious, I would remove their NTFS permissions to the root also. I'd be a bit worried it might break something for them though.

Comment: Okay, what about all those SID ownerships? Could there be any problem if I change all those ownerships to my account?

Comment: Yeah it's not good security practice to do that really. We had someone who had to take ownership of everything on their C drive recently because of a permissions mistake they needed to recover from. After they salvaged their data, the consensus was that the best thing would be if they reinstalled Windows to reset all the ownership and permissions to their safe defaults. You can't easily reverse sweeping changes like that. Permissions and ownership on user data is one thing but you need to tread much more carefully with OS folders. Yes, it's a bit messy... but it's supposed to be that way!